# Paypal Rest API : Difference between Paypal execute and auth-capture

Tags: paypal

I am developing a system in which I have to integrate paypal. In the backend the system itself uses an internal API(I do have many systems communicates to core like web, mobile app etc). Consider the case of web, I am planning to approve the payment using the Paypal Rest API, so the user will be redirected to Paypal and approves the payment and then the system communicates with the internal api and then the actual payment has to be completed.

When going through the docs, I can see `Payment->Execute` need to be done after the approval. Also I can see Authorize and, Capture later as in other payment systems. So I am confused with  the significance of execute method?

Answer (score 9):

When you create the payment, you can the intent of the payment to be 'sale', 'authorize' or 'order'. For each of these you need to call payment->Execute, but the difference is in what happens after

1. When set to sale, payment will immediately be processed and funds transferred as soon as possible.
2. When set to authorize, you get back an authorization_id. The funds will be on hold for 3 days within which you use that id to to a capture on the payment to have the transaction processed.
3. When set to order, you get back an order_id. The order does not put fund on hold, but you can call authorize against the order to put the funds on hold and later call capture on that order to process the transaction and transfer funds.